# OkHttp MockWebServer fails to accept connections in android P (API 28) Instrumentation Test

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, okhttp, mockwebserver

When I have updated my sdk version from API 26 to API 28, OKHttp mockserver fails to run in the device/emulator in my android instrumentation test. It ran perfectly in the older versions. I have checked in the [Network Config](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config)

```
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
       <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
          <domain includeSubdomains="false">localhost</domain>
       <domain-config>
    </domain-config>
 </network-security-config>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out by changing the cleartext value in the base-config. May be it will useful to some one.

```
<network-security-config> 
   <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" /> 
</network-security-config>
```